# How do I download the latest version of modernizr - and where?

Tags: amazon-aws

I'm currently running modernizr 2.5.3, and Im using Amazon Web Services for hosting.  Where and how can I get the latest release?

Comment: [Recommendations for sites and resources](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) -- `Questions that ask for recommendations of external websites or resources attract lots of self promotion and spam answers. In addition, answers to such questions quickly become out of date. Such questions are closed as off-topic.`

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this the other day when I was answering your other question.  The official Modernizr download page is here: https://modernizr.com/download/?setclasses

cdnjs has a many versions of the software available that can be used from their CDN, or which you can download and re-host easily: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modernizr